# SonarQube and Sonarsource's sonarlint plugin for Intellej compatiblity

Tags: java-8, sonarqube, version, sonarlint-intellij

We are using Enterprise support Sonarqube version 6.7.x. The current latest version of sonarlint plugin 8.3.0 is not comparable with my sonarqube 6.7.x.
I tried some more version but none of them worked.  Can some one please suggest the Sonarlint version which is compatible with Sonarqube 8.3.0.
Or at lease direct me in the right path.
My project is on Java 8 and I have Java 11 installed as well.  Upgrading Sonarqube is not an option as this is an enterprise setup and is shared throughout the organisation.

Answer (score 0):

SonarLint version 5.0 dropped support of SonarQube < 7.9 for connected mode as mentioned on their marketplace [page](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7973-sonarlint/versions/stable/123082).

I suggest trying the previous SonarLint version which is [4.16](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7973-sonarlint/versions/stable/119180).